# Who or what is Asaph?

Tags: psalms

> Psalm 79:1 A psalm of **Asaph**.

> 2 Chronicles 29:30 King Hezekiah and his officials ordered the Levites to praise the LORD with the words of David and of **Asaph** the seer. So they sang praises with gladness and bowed down and worshiped.

Are these two Asaphs related?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Who or what is Asaph?**

Recommend you read 1 Chronicles Chapters 6, 15,   25:1-6, 2 Chronicles 29:30 and 35:15
Asaph was a Levi through his son Gershom.

1 Chronicles 6:39 , 43 (NASB)

> 39 Heman’s brother Asaph stood at his right hand, even Asaph the son
> of Berechiah, the son of Shimea, 43 the son of Jahath, **the son of
> Gershom, the son of Levi.**

1 Chronicles 15: 17-29 NASB

The Levites appointed Asaph as a singer and player of cymbals to accompany the Ark from Obed-edom's house to "the city of David"

> 25 So it was David, with the elders of Israel and the captains over
> thousands, who went to bring up the ark of the covenant of the Lord
> from the house of Obed-edom with joy

.
1 Chronicles 6:31-44 NASB

Asaph, with Herman and Eltham, served before the tabernacle in directing music and singing.